# Sort a CSV file by one column, allowing a specified number of duplicates in another column

Tags: shell, csv, awk, grep

I have a file containing the following information on ~23,000 cities around the world:

population:country code:city:continent

```
20470:ZM:Samfya:Africa
20149:ZM:Sesheke:Africa
18638:ZM:Siavonga:Africa
26459:ZW:Beitbridge:Africa
37423:ZW:Bindura:Africa
699385:ZW:Bulawayo:Africa
47294:ZW:Chegutu:Africa
61739:ZW:Chinhoyi:Africa
18860:ZW:Chipinge:Africa
28205:ZW:Chiredzi:Africa
```

I would like to keep only the lines which contain the four largest cities (by population) in each country.
I thought maybe I could sort by population, and then only allow a certain number of duplicates in the second column - the latter part is what I can't figure out.

Is there some way I can achieve this using e.g. awk/grep/sed/sort?

Comment: Yes. But this isn't a code writing service, so show us what you've tried and what you're having problems with and ask specific questions about the parts you don't understand.

Comment: @twalberg Sorry if it's a rubbish question. I didn't really have any significant code to share as all I could do was sort by population. I tried googling about awk but there's so much to it and as I haven't used it before I hoped someone here who has would have no problem helping me out. Is this the wrong way to use stack overflow?

Comment: You can start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more info on how the site is intended to be used, including what types of questions to ask or not, and how to ask them (what information to include)... It's not that it's a "rubbish question" - it is actually pretty clearly stated - but it's expected that you show some initial effort and have something more specific than "is this possible?"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rewritten solution from the over complicated solution to Vytenis.

```
sort -t: -k1rn file | awk -F: 'count[$2]++<5'
699385:ZW:Bulawayo:Africa
61739:ZW:Chinhoyi:Africa
47294:ZW:Chegutu:Africa
37423:ZW:Bindura:Africa
28205:ZW:Chiredzi:Africa
20470:ZM:Samfya:Africa
20149:ZM:Sesheke:Africa
18638:ZM:Siavonga:Africa
```

Answer (score 0):

This prints sorted results:

```
sort -t: -k1rn  | awk -F: '{count[$2]++; print count[$2]":"$0}' | awk -F: '$1<5' | cut -d: -f 2-
```

Comment: All the long `awk` part can be shorten to one simple `awk -F: 'count[$2]++<5'`